# Query Builder with multiple sub queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Any ideas how use query builder with this query?

```
SELECT * from 
    (SELECT * from table2) t1,
    (SELECT * from table2) t2,
    (SELECT * from table3) t3,
    (SELECT * from table4) t4
```

Comment: You are showing a massive cross join query.  Is that what you really intend to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Its okay i just need to have the query builder for that. I'm just asking basic query to be translated into query builder.